# Better API to retrieve longitude/latitude data

Tags: jquery, json, api

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
  $("#hello").html('Latitude: ' + data.latitude +
        '<br /> Longitude: ' + data.longitude +
        '<br /> Country: ' + data.address.country);
});​
```

I'm often used above code to get the `latitude,longitude,country`. But a lot of times it's not working properly

```
Latitude: 0
Longitude: 0
Country: Unknown
```

Is there any better API to get those results?

Comment: You may want to modify the title of your question to something along the lines of "Better API to retreive longitude/latitude data". JSON data is pretty vague.

Comment: If you want to get the latlong from an address i recommend google maps. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses

Comment: @ Despertar :I changed my title as you suggested

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in HTML5 geolocation API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used smart-ip as a fallback for HTML5's geolocation API, and never really had any problems with it?

```
$.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/?callback=?', function (data) {
    $("#hello").html('Latitude: ' + data.latitude +
        '<br /> Longitude: ' + data.longitude +
        '<br /> Country: ' + data.countryName);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mry4/)

Google would also be a good alternative, but the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) for Google Maps clearly states:

> You must not use or display the Content (from the Maps API) without a
>   corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so
>   in the Maps APIs Documentation, or through written permission from
>   Google.